# How to directly mount external NFS share/volume in kubernetes(1.10.3)

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am using kubernetes : v1.10.3 , i have one external NFS server which i am able to mount anywhere ( any physical machines). I want to mount this NFS directly to pod/container . I tried but every time i am getting error.  don't want to use privileges, kindly help me to fix.

> ERROR: MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "nfs" : mount failed: exit
>   status 32 Mounting command: systemd-run Mounting arguments:
>   --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/d65eb963-68be-11e8-8181-00163eeb9788/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs
>   --scope -- mount -t nfs 10.225.241.137:/stagingfs/alt/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/d65eb963-68be-11e8-8181-00163eeb9788/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs
>   Output: Running scope as unit run-43393.scope. mount: wrong fs type,
>   bad option, bad superblock on 10.225.241.137:/stagingfs/alt/, missing
>   codepage or helper program, or other error (for several filesystems
>   (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount. helper program)
>   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.

```
NFS server :  mount -t nfs 10.X.X.137:/stagingfs/alt   /alt
```

I added two things for volume here  but getting error every time.

first :

```
"volumeMounts": [
          {
            "name": "nfs",
            "mountPath": "/alt"
          }

        ],
```

Second :

```
 "volumes": [
  {
    "name": "nfs",
    "nfs": {
      "server": "10.X.X.137",
      "path": "/stagingfs/alt/"
    }
  }

],
```

---------------------complete yaml --------------------------------

```
{
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "jboss",
    "namespace": "staging",
    "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/staging/deployments/jboss",
    "uid": "6a85e235-68b4-11e8-8181-00163eeb9788",
    "resourceVersion": "609891",
    "generation": 2,
    "creationTimestamp": "2018-06-05T11:34:32Z",
    "labels": {
      "k8s-app": "jboss"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "2"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "k8s-app": "jboss"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "jboss",
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "k8s-app": "jboss"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
          "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "nfs",
        "nfs": {
          "server": "10.X.X.137",
          "path": "/stagingfs/alt/"
        }
      }

    ],
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "jboss",
            "image": "my.abc.com/alt:7.1_1.1",
            "resources": {},
            "volumeMounts": [
          {
            "name": "nfs",
            "mountPath": "/alt"
          }

        ],
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
            "securityContext": {
              "privileged": true
            }
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "securityContext": {},
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {
      "type": "RollingUpdate",
      "rollingUpdate": {
        "maxUnavailable": "25%",
        "maxSurge": "25%"
      }
    },
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 10,
    "progressDeadlineSeconds": 600
  },
  "status": {
    "observedGeneration": 2,
    "replicas": 1,
    "updatedReplicas": 1,
    "readyReplicas": 1,
    "availableReplicas": 1,
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Available",
        "status": "True",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2018-06-05T11:35:45Z",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2018-06-05T11:35:45Z",
        "reason": "MinimumReplicasAvailable",
        "message": "Deployment has minimum availability."
      },
      {
        "type": "Progressing",
        "status": "True",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2018-06-05T11:35:46Z",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2018-06-05T11:34:32Z",
        "reason": "NewReplicaSetAvailable",
        "message": "ReplicaSet \"jboss-8674444985\" has successfully progressed."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Regards
Anupam Narayan

Comment: You should format your question better.

Comment: NFS mount error 32 might be caused by rpcbind problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552277/nfs-volume-mount-results-in-exit-code-32-on-in-kubernetes

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the error log:

```
for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount. helper program
```

According to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525243/why-do-i-get-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-error), you might be missing the nfs-commons package which you can install using `sudo apt install nfs-common`

Comment: Hi, Even after installation of utills & common on Dokerfile RUN yum install -y nfs-utils nfs-common rpcbind nfslock still i am getting same error

Comment: @Anupam the installation needs to be done on the node