# Kubernetes PVC mount with xfs fails with code 32

Tags: linux, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a `Pod` mounting a volume from a `PersistentVolumeClaim`. The PVC uses a `StorageClass` provisioning EBS volumes with the `xfs` filesystem. The setup is as below:

```
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/opt/st1"
          name: opt-st1
      volumes:
      - name: opt-st1
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: st1-xfs-pvc
```

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: st1-xfs-pvc
  labels:
    app: st1-xfs-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: st1-xfs-sc
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Gi
```

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: st1-xfs-sc
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: st1
  fsType: xfs
reclaimPolicy: Retain
mountOptions:
  - debug
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - us-east-1a
```

When I run this setup on an EKS-based cluster (version 1.13), I get the following error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                From                                    Message
  ----     ------                  ----               ----                                    -------
  Normal   Scheduled               45s                default-scheduler                       Successfully assigned jira-node-deployment-5f4f59c44d-jbc4c to ip-10-237-86-124.ec2.internal
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume      40s (x4 over 44s)  attachdetach-controller                 AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-50996814-bf53-11e9-848f-0ec61103f6e0" : "Error attaching EBS volume \"vol-077709885f54252c7\"" to instance "i-0fe9867c4129f058e" since volume is in "creating" state
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  33s                attachdetach-controller                 AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-50996814-bf53-11e9-848f-0ec61103f6e0"
  Warning  FailedMount             24s                kubelet, ip-10-237-86-124.ec2.internal  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-50996814-bf53-11e9-848f-0ec61103f6e0" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1a/vol-077709885f54252c7 --scope -- mount -t xfs -o debug,defaults /dev/xvdbp /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1a/vol-077709885f54252c7
Output: Running scope as unit run-979548.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1a/vol-077709885f54252c7: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdbp, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
  Warning  FailedMount  22s  kubelet, ip-10-237-86-124.ec2.internal  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-50996814-bf53-11e9-848f-0ec61103f6e0" : mount failed: exit status 32
```

If I connect to the Kubernetes worker, and run the same command manually, I am able to reproduce the error:

```
$ systemd-run --description='Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1a/vol-068d85e415249b896' --scope -- mount -t xfs -o debug,defaults /dev/xvdcg /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1a/vol-068d85e415249b896
Running scope as unit run-982245.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1a/vol-077709885f54252c7: mount point does not exist.

$ mkdir /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1a/vol-077709885f54252c7

$ systemd-run --description='Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1a/vol-068d85e415249b896' --scope -- mount -t xfs -o debug,defaults /dev/xvdcg /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1a/vol-068d85e415249b896
Running scope as unit run-982245.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1a/vol-077709885f54252c7: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdbp, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

$ echo $?
32
```

I noticed that by removing the `debug` option from the command and run it again, then the volume is mounted fine...

```
$ systemd-run --description='Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1a/vol-077709885f54252c7' --scope -- mount -t xfs -o defaults /dev/xvdbp /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-1a/vol-077709885f54252c7
Running scope as unit run-986177.scope.
```

... and the `Pod` runs fine a few seconds after that:

```
  Normal   Pulled       50s                  kubelet, ip-10-237-86-124.ec2.internal  Container image "nginx:alpine" already present on machine
  Normal   Created      49s                  kubelet, ip-10-237-86-124.ec2.internal  Created container
  Normal   Started      46s                  kubelet, ip-10-237-86-124.ec2.internal  Started container
```

I also noticed that if I use `ext4` instead of `xfs`, the setup described above works fine.

Comment: @jww In the "kubernetes" tag it says "KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Kubernetes is an open-source platform designed to automate deployment, scaling, and operation of application containers, across multiple hosts and/or clouds. Questions should pertain to the scripting part. Questions about configuring servers should be asked on https://serverfault.com or https://superuser.com" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes)

Comment: @jww My question is not about configuring servers - it does pertain to the scripting part. I see there's also Devops Beta (https://devops.stackexchange.com/) but it seems to have far fewer questions on Kubernetes than here. When someone's Q&A gets downvoted because of personal opinion, we are discouraging the users from sharing their knowledge, which I am sure is not the goal of stack exchange

Comment: @jww Finally, if only "programming and development" questions are allowed on Stack Overflow, we should either edit the tag description to clarify what is considered a programming question from the K8s perspective, or remove the tag altogether

Comment: There are better sites to field questions why the `systemd-run` command fails for Kubernetes. Troubleshooting a failed mount command does not elevate "programming and development".

Comment: @jww The root cause was not the `systemd-run` command. It was a configuration mistake in the Storage Class. This has nothing to do with server configuration. Consider a program that has a bug that causes problems on the server it is running on (e.g: performance bottlenecks or full disks) - the symptom has to do with the server, but the cause is 100% programming-related).   Also, there are several questions similar to this one on stackoverflow, with lots of views, answers and upvotes - just do a search for "kubernetes" here and you will see what I mean.

Comment: You can find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552277/nfs-volume-mount-results-in-exit-code-32-on-in-kubernetes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while I realized that the `debug` action was added by myself in the `StorageClass` config:

```
mountOptions:
  - debug
```

After I removed these two lines, everything works as expected.

Comment: I'm also trying to add xfs storage class to mongo operator db resource but getting error saying that "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdch, missing codepage or helper program, or other error." Even I tried to remove this mount options block, but stil no luck